# Facebook like button's iframe

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, facebook-like

I put an facebook like iframe related to each post of some webpage as so

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href={$post_url}&amp;
layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=90&amp;action=like&amp;
font=verdana&amp;colorscheme=light" allowtransparency="true" style="border:
medium none; overflow: hidden; width: 90px; height: 21px;" frameborder="0"
scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

The count works well but when clicking the like button, no popup is showed to enter a message. Could someone explain ? (my site uses an app facebook, and there are og meta for each page, could that causes problem ?)

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/:

> *“send - specifies whether to include a Send button with the Like button. **This only works with the XFBML version.**”*

So you will have to embed your like buttons using the JavaScript SDK instead of the iframe version if you want to have the send button.

Comment: Ok so if I want this popup to display I need two buttons just to enter a message : one for like and another for sending  ??

Comment: No, it’s still only the Like button plugin you have to implement – but as mentioned, in a different way.

Comment: @CBroe I think the OP is asking about the the small popup that appears under the like button when it's clicked to enter a custom message with the like.